# Detect Ctrl + S in Console

Tags: c#, input, console, modifiers

I'm developing a console application in which I need to detect several hotkeys such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. Here's a part of the code that I use to recognize these hotkeys:

```
ConsoleKeyInfo input = Console.ReadKey(true);

if (input.Modifiers == ConsoleModifiers.Control)
{
    if (input.Key == ConsoleKey.N)
    {
        // ...
    }
    else if (input.Key == ConsoleKey.O)
    {
        // ...
    }
    else if (input.Key == ConsoleKey.S)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

The code above works without any issues for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>. But, I can't get it to work for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. After doing some quick testing, I found out that pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> doesn't even do anything (meaning that the program is still waiting for the user to type something).

This issue only occurs with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. Using some simple `if` statements for any other modifier (<kbd>Shift</kbd> for example) and key (<kbd>N</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd>, etc) works fine.

Why does this happen? Is there a special meaning to the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> combination? Is it possible to make this work? If yes, how?

Comment: CTRL-S is caught by the console program to pause output. That's why it's not passed on to your application. I do not know how to disable it.

Comment: I found this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9951471/2524589

Answer (score 0):

```
protected override  bool  ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (msg.Msg == 256)
    {
        //if the user pressed control + s
        if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.S))
        {

        }
        //if the user pressed control + o 
        else if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.O))
        {

        }
        //if the user pressed control + n 
        else if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.N))
        {

        }
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Comment: How is this supposed to be called? Where does the `msg` and `keyData` come from?

Answer (score 0):

With help from [ThreeStarProgrammer57](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48778046/5698805), I came up with this solution for my own console application.

You need to configure the console by using [SetConsoleMode](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.setconsolemode) and passing *"`ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT | ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT | ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS` as suggested by oconnor0"*.

Import the needed kernel functions:

```cs
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool SetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleHandle, uint dwMode);
[Flags]
private enum ConsoleInputModes : uint
{
    ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT = 0x0001,
    ENABLE_LINE_INPUT = 0x0002,
    ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT = 0x0004,
    ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT = 0x0008,
    ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT = 0x0010,
    ENABLE_INSERT_MODE = 0x0020,
    ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE = 0x0040,
    ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS = 0x0080,
    ENABLE_AUTO_POSITION = 0x0100
}

[Flags]
private enum ConsoleOutputModes : uint
{
    ENABLE_PROCESSED_OUTPUT = 0x0001,
    ENABLE_WRAP_AT_EOL_OUTPUT = 0x0002,
    ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING = 0x0004,
    DISABLE_NEWLINE_AUTO_RETURN = 0x0008,
    ENABLE_LVB_GRID_WORLDWIDE = 0x0010
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);
static int STD_INPUT_HANDLE = -10;
```

And use them in your program as following:

```cs
// Add this section to your code:
SetConsoleMode(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), (uint)(
    ConsoleInputModes.ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT |
    ConsoleInputModes.ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT  |
    ConsoleInputModes.ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS
));
// ------------------------------

ConsoleKeyInfo input = Console.ReadKey(true);

if (input.Modifiers == ConsoleModifiers.Control)
{
    if (input.Key == ConsoleKey.N)
    {
        // ...
    }
    else if (input.Key == ConsoleKey.O)
    {
        // ...
    }
    else if (input.Key == ConsoleKey.S)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

This solution will not only allow you to capture <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> keystrokes, but also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>!