# Ctrl-S input event in Windows console with ReadConsoleInputW

Tags: winapi, rust, console-application

I am using `ReadConsoleInputW` to read Windows 10 console input. I want to be able to detect when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> is pressed. Using the code I have, I can detect <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> without issue, but I'm not seeing anything for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. Is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> even detectable?

The below is the sequence of `INPUT_RECORD` I read when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> a few times, followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.

```
Key { key_down: true, repeat_count: 1, key_code: 17, scan_code: 29, wide_char: 0, control_key_state: 40 }
Key { key_down: true, repeat_count: 1, key_code: 17, scan_code: 29, wide_char: 0, control_key_state: 40 }
Key { key_down: true, repeat_count: 1, key_code: 17, scan_code: 29, wide_char: 0, control_key_state: 40 }
Key { key_down: true, repeat_count: 1, key_code: 17, scan_code: 29, wide_char: 0, control_key_state: 40 }
Key { key_down: true, repeat_count: 1, key_code: 17, scan_code: 29, wide_char: 0, control_key_state: 40 }
Key { key_down: true, repeat_count: 1, key_code: 17, scan_code: 29, wide_char: 0, control_key_state: 40 }
Key { key_down: true, repeat_count: 1, key_code: 17, scan_code: 29, wide_char: 0, control_key_state: 40 }
Key { key_down: true, repeat_count: 1, key_code: 17, scan_code: 29, wide_char: 0, control_key_state: 40 }
Key { key_down: true, repeat_count: 1, key_code: 81, scan_code: 16, wide_char: 17, control_key_state: 40 }
```

If it matters, this is in Rust using `wio`.

Comment: Which terminal emulator are you using? Are you using `cmd.exe`? Powershell? Something like bash? Could the terminal emulator program be intercepting that key combo?

Comment: Can you try to disable `ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT` using [`SetConsoleMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686033(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: I'm using `cmd.exe`. I'll try disabling `ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT` tonight. Thanks.

Comment: It seems that `ENABLE_LINE_INPUT` is the culprit! Please see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `SetConsoleMode` with `ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT | ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT | ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS` as the second argument (thus disabling `ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT`) did the trick.

Comment: +1, as you helped me find the solution. However, I found that ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT is not culprit, please see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

oconnor0's answer helped me find the solution.

However, I could not get ctrl-s event by disabling `ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT`, so I tried using only `ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT | ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT | ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS` as suggested by oconnor0. This worked, but this means `ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT` is not the culrpit!

So I tried:

```
//This didn't work
if (!GetConsoleMode(hConsoleInput, &lpMode)) Error();
lpMode &= ~(ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT);
if (!SetConsoleMode(hConsoleInput, lpMode)) Error();

//This worked
if (!GetConsoleMode(hConsoleInput, &lpMode)) Error();
lpMode &= ~(ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT | ENABLE_LINE_INPUT);
if (!SetConsoleMode(hConsoleInput, lpMode)) Error();
```

Disabling `ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT` forces you to disable `ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT` (see msdn), but it isn't the culprit because:

```
//This didn't work either
if (!GetConsoleMode(hConsoleInput, &lpMode)) Error();
lpMode &= ~(ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT | ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT);
if (!SetConsoleMode(hConsoleInput, lpMode)) Error();
```

**So this means that `ENABLE_LINE_INPUT` is the culprit!**

It's not clear why though:

> ENABLE_LINE_INPUT 0x0002   The ReadFile or ReadConsole function returns
>   only when a carriage return character is read. If this mode is
>   disabled, the functions return when one or more characters are
>   available.

Comment: Clearly the ENABLE_LINE_INPUT does things that are not documented by MS.

Comment: Normally we wouldn't want line editing and history for a low-level read anyway. But for anyone who wants to read Ctrl+S normally with line-input mode, disable extended text selection in the console defaults / properties. This corresponds to the "ExtendedEditKey" DWORD value in "HKCU\Console" (or a window-title subkey). Unfortunately this also disables immediate access to the new text selection features in Windows 10, such as Shift+ArrowKeys. Instead we have to first enter mark mode via Ctrl+M.

Comment: This should be selected as the answer. Though I'd prefer if it simply cut to the chase instead of reviewing everything that doesn't work. Pausing the console via Ctrl+S is a feature of line-input mode with extended editing keys disabled. Programmatically the console API only has the course-grained control to disable line-input mode, but that's good enough for most cases where we need this for a low-level read.